# How to open .pdf URL in Safari browser in swift

Tags: swift, safari

Here i trying to open `URL` with **.pdf** extension in *Safari Browser*. But code is not working I'm getting nil in `URL`. But when i tried `URL` like **"www.google.com"** it's working fine

- Code

  ```
     let cerificateURl = "https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/file-sample_150kB.pdf"

      guard let url = URL(string: cerificateURl) else {
        return
      }

     if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
         UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
     } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
     }
  ```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Encode that `URL` by using `addingPercentEncoding`.

Comment: There is a whitespace **"Rahul _"** in your string. If you percent encode it it should work. `.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)`. You will also need to add your domain to the info plist App Transport Security Settings Exception Domains list https://www.dropbox.com/s/hi684jdomlrl5r4/app%20transport%20security.jpg?dl=1

Comment: If your server supports https you should use it

Answer (score -2):

Try This one.

```
let cerificateURl = "https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/file-sample_150kB.pdf"

if let myURL = URL(string: url) {
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: myURL) {
        webView.load(data, mimeType: "application/pdf", characterEncodingName: "", baseURL: myURL
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I've to open pdf url in browser not in webView!

Comment: You should use URLSession dataTask to download your data asynchronously. This would freeze your app if there is no internet connection. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1407613-datatask

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "your web pdf file link here or you can set from local directory path") 
else { return }
UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```

Comment: Sorry but you've to read the question first, because your answer code is same as question code, and also answer code is not proper formatted.

Comment: This code is working fine in my app , so i try to help with this code...
In my App : Call API -> Get PDF url -> Open browser to view PDF.
it's working fine in my app.

Comment: I have been already tried with code but it's not working and i'm getting nil url in string to url conversion.Please see the question!

Comment: @LeoDabus It's not working in any of my devices and simulators!

Comment: @LeoDabus Updated please check

Comment: @LeoDabus encoded url is also not working for me

Comment: @BhaveshM.Sarsawa it's working fine , look at demo video with your PDF link here  https://www.dropbox.com/s/9graybur8cmuz2l/Screen%20Recording%202020-02-17%20at%2012.33.43%20PM.mov?dl=0

Comment: @LeoDabus with my original url code is not working neither with url encoding nor without url encoding!!!

Comment: @LeoDabus yes supports

Comment: same working dropbox.com/s/3vpuhucd2fgoqoe/pdf%20test.png?dl=1